# Как к диалоговому окну прикрепить свой TitleBar?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qdialog, framelesswindowhint

**Код диалогового окна**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(478, 143)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 211, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(9)
        self.buttonBox.setFont(font)
        self.buttonBox.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.buttonBox.setStyleSheet("border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 75 11pt \"Montserrat\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setCenterButtons(True)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 301, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 50, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 75 14pt \"Montserrat\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 321, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(9)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 75 16pt \"Montserrat\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) # type: ignore
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject) # type: ignore
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Importing file"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Browse"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Convert objection to txt"))
```

**Код TitleBar**:

```
class Ui_tbWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, tbWidget):
        tbWidget.setObjectName("tbWidget")
        tbWidget.resize(600, 40)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(tbWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        tbWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        tbWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        tbWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(tbWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.tbWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(tbWidget)
        self.tbWidget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setStyleSheet("QWidget#tbWidget_2{\n"
                                      "    background-color: #009688;\n"
                                      "}")
        self.tbWidget_2.setObjectName("tbWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.tbWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setObjectName("tbWidget_5")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.tbLabel_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Objection.lol', self.tbWidget_5,
                                          alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tbLabel_6.setObjectName("tbLabel_6")
        self.tbLabel_6.setStyleSheet(
            "#tbLabel_6 {color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 22px;}")

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tbLabel_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.tbWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
                                      "    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);\n"
                                      "    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                      "    border-radius:1px;\n"
                                      "    font-size:18px;\n"

                                      # ----> "    font-family:dripicons-v2;\n"                        # <---- убрал

                                      "}\n"
                                      "QPushButton:hover{\n"
                                      "    background-color:rgb(49, 48, 53);\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "QPushButton#closeButton:hover{\n"
                                      "    background-color:rgb(232, 17, 35);\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "QPushButton:pressed{\n"
                                      "    padding-top:5px;\n"
                                      "    padding-left:5px;\n"
                                      "}")
        self.tbWidget_3.setObjectName("tbWidget_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.closeButton.setFont(font)

        self.closeButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.closeButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.closeButton.setObjectName("closeButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.closeButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        self.buttonMaximum = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.buttonMaximum.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.buttonMaximum.setFont(font)
        self.buttonMaximum.setObjectName("buttonMaximum")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonMaximum, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        # !!! +++
        self.buttonNormal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)  # +++
        self.buttonNormal.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.buttonNormal.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.buttonNormal.setFont(font)
        self.buttonNormal.setObjectName("buttonNormal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonNormal, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.buttonMinimum = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.buttonMinimum.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.buttonMinimum.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.buttonMinimum.setFont(font)
        self.buttonMinimum.setObjectName("buttonMinimum")  # buttonMinimum tbPushButton
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonMinimum, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tbWidget_2)

        self.retranslateUi(tbWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(tbWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, tbWidget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        tbWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("tbWidget", "Form"))

        self.buttonMinimum.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "0"))
        self.closeButton.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "r"))
        self.buttonMaximum.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "1"))
        self.buttonNormal.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "2"))  # +++


class TitleBar(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_tbWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.buttonNormal.setVisible(False)
        self.parent = parent  # +++
        self.buttonMinimum.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.buttonMaximum.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.buttonNormal.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.closeButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

        self.buttonMinimum.clicked.connect(self.parent.showMinimized)
        self.buttonMaximum.clicked.connect(self.parent.showMaximized)
        self.buttonNormal.clicked.connect(self.parent.showNormal)
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.parent.close)

        self.parent.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, target, event):
        if isinstance(event, QWindowStateChangeEvent):
            if self.parent.isVisible() and not self.parent.isMinimized():
                # Скрыть кнопку максимизации, если ток максимален
                self.buttonMaximum.setVisible(not self.parent.isMaximized())
                self.buttonNormal.setVisible(self.parent.isMaximized())
        return super(TitleBar, self).eventFilter(target, event)
```

---

**ВАЖНО, ЧТОБЫ ОКНО МОГЛО ДВИГАТЬСЯ И КНОПКИ НА TITLEBAR РАБОТАЛИ И ЧТОБЫ СТАНДАРТНЫЙ TITLEBAR БЫЛ УБРАН (СТАНДАРТНЫЙ TITLEBAR НИЖЕ)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QTableWidget, QLineEdit

from q1442791_titleBar import TitleBar                                  # +++


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(478, 143)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 211, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(9)
        self.buttonBox.setFont(font)
        self.buttonBox.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.buttonBox.setStyleSheet("border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 75 11pt \"Montserrat\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setCenterButtons(True)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 301, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 50, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 75 14pt \"Montserrat\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 321, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(9)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 75 16pt \"Montserrat\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) # type: ignore
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject) # type: ignore
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Importing file"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Browse"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Convert objection to txt"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        
        self.titleBar = TitleBar(self)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 10, 10) 
        layout.addWidget(self.titleBar, 1, 1, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 2, 1, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 3, 1, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox, 4, 1, 1, 2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**q1442791_titleBar.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_tbWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, tbWidget):
        tbWidget.setObjectName("tbWidget")
        tbWidget.resize(600, 40)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(tbWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        tbWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        tbWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        tbWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(tbWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.tbWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(tbWidget)
        self.tbWidget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setStyleSheet("QWidget#tbWidget_2{\n"
                                      "    background-color: #009688;\n"
                                      "}")
        self.tbWidget_2.setObjectName("tbWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.tbWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setObjectName("tbWidget_5")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.tbLabel_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Objection.lol', self.tbWidget_5,
                                          alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tbLabel_6.setObjectName("tbLabel_6")
        self.tbLabel_6.setStyleSheet(
            "#tbLabel_6 {color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 22px;}")

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tbLabel_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.tbWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
                                      "    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);\n"
                                      "    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                      "    border-radius:1px;\n"
                                      "    font-size:18px;\n"

                                      # ----> "    font-family:dripicons-v2;\n"                        # <---- убрал

                                      "}\n"
                                      "QPushButton:hover{\n"
                                      "    background-color:rgb(49, 48, 53);\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "QPushButton#closeButton:hover{\n"
                                      "    background-color:rgb(232, 17, 35);\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "QPushButton:pressed{\n"
                                      "    padding-top:5px;\n"
                                      "    padding-left:5px;\n"
                                      "}")
        self.tbWidget_3.setObjectName("tbWidget_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.closeButton.setFont(font)

        self.closeButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.closeButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.closeButton.setObjectName("closeButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.closeButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        self.buttonMaximum = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.buttonMaximum.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.buttonMaximum.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.buttonMaximum.setFont(font)
        self.buttonMaximum.setObjectName("buttonMaximum")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonMaximum, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.buttonNormal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.buttonNormal.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.buttonNormal.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.buttonNormal.setFont(font)
        self.buttonNormal.setObjectName("buttonNormal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonNormal, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.buttonMinimum = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.buttonMinimum.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.buttonMinimum.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Webdings")
        self.buttonMinimum.setFont(font)
        self.buttonMinimum.setObjectName("buttonMinimum")  # buttonMinimum tbPushButton
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonMinimum, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tbWidget_2)

        self.retranslateUi(tbWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(tbWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, tbWidget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        tbWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("tbWidget", "Form"))
        self.buttonMinimum.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "0"))
        self.closeButton.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "r"))
        self.buttonMaximum.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "1"))
        self.buttonNormal.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "2"))  # +++


class TitleBar(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_tbWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.mPos = None                                                  # +++

        self.buttonNormal.setVisible(False)
        self.parent = parent  
        self.buttonMinimum.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.buttonMaximum.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.buttonNormal.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.closeButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

        self.buttonMinimum.clicked.connect(self.parent.showMinimized)
        self.buttonMaximum.clicked.connect(self.parent.showMaximized)
        self.buttonNormal.clicked.connect(self.parent.showNormal)
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.parent.close)

        self.parent.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, target, event):
        if isinstance(event, QtGui.QWindowStateChangeEvent):
            if self.parent.isVisible() and not self.parent.isMinimized():
                # Скрыть кнопку максимизации, если ток максимален
                self.buttonMaximum.setVisible(not self.parent.isMaximized())
                self.buttonNormal.setVisible(self.parent.isMaximized())
        return super(TitleBar, self).eventFilter(target, event)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.mPos = event.pos()        

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.mPos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.parent.isMaximized():
            return
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and self.mPos:
            pos = event.pos() - self.mPos
            self.parent.move(self.parent.pos() + pos)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]